# Can't remove padding/margin of a floated element

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

I have floated elements which I can't remove the padding and/or margin, even with CSS reset.

See at http://ogabrielsantos.com.br/dev/, when hover the `Ilustradores` menu, each image need to have not a padding, margin, etc.

I can paste some codes here, but, I think seeing at the website is more easy and fast, because I have to put a large css/html block here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display:block` on your images in menu. Images are by default inline elements and they are aligned to the text baseline (their bottom line is on the text baseline) and there are few pixels under the baseline, which is what you see.

Comment: Good, this work, but not 100%. With `display:block` I have like 1px of margin, at the left and bottom of element.

Comment: Your image seems to include a 1px transparent area at the bottom. Can't that be what you are seeing?

Comment: Yep, sorry, Designer send-me the image like this.. Thanks for help ;)